# Reload div without blinking using ajax jQuery on Codeigniter 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I spend around five hour searching a solution. Here is my simple ajax code:

```js
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>chat/user-list",
        cache : false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data != $("#usuarios_chat").html(data)){
                $("#usuarios_chat").replace(data);
            }else{
                $("#usuarios_chat").append(data);
            }
        },
      })
    },3000);
    </script>
```

The code works perfect, but when some data is changed or new detected all data is being duplicated when is displayed.

Image before change or insert data on database.

[image: IMAGE BEFORE CHANGE OR INSERT DATA ON DATABASE]

Image after data changed or inserted on database

[image: IMAGE AFTER DATA CHANGED OR INSERTED ON DATABASE]

Updated: I updated the above code were I got the desired target is done but the blinking when I fetch data still present.

Comment: Because you are ALWAYS appending it, you need to REPLACE it instead.

Comment: `$("#usuarios_chat").html(data);` ?? , no need if condition

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestion, can you check my updated code post? I really appreciate if I need to implement something else. I am using it on CI 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will replace the old data with the new one.

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>chat/user-list",
    cache : false,
    success: function(data){
        if(data != $("#usuarios_chat").html(data)){
            $("#usuarios_chat").remove();
        }else{
            $("#usuarios_chat").append(data);
        }
    },
  })
},3000);
</script>
```